# To combine 2 document element id values

Tags: asp.net

In the below code i have 2 document element id of javascript I like to combine please any one help me how to combine 2 ids values.

code behind

```
txtField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:ValidateRegExp(document.getElementById('" + txtField.ClientID + "').value, '" + hidRegExp.ClientID + "');");
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to combine the client ID of two server side controls and pass that to a javascript function.

Then this is what you should do:

```
txtField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:ValidateRegExp('" + txtField.ClientID + hidRegExp.ClientID + "');");
```

Or, with a separator between the ID's:

```
txtField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:ValidateRegExp('" + txtField.ClientID + "|" + hidRegExp.ClientID + "');");
```